# AngularJS loses watch on object property when object is replaced

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I replace an object that contains a property that is being watched with another instance of that object... AngularJS seems to lose the reference to that property... which I can understand... but what is a good way to reconnect that members property in, say, an ng-repeat directive. For example...

HTML

```
﻿﻿﻿﻿<div ng-repeat="portfolio in data.portfolios">
  {{ portfolio.name }}
<div>
```

JS

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.portfolios = [
    { Name: "aaa" },
    { Name: "bbb" }
];

 $scope.portfoliosService.loadPortfolios(clientId, true, true)
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });
```

Note: response.data contains an array called portfolios.

Comment: if you want to preserve the existing objects in the array, you could use `angular.merge()` (1.4x+) to merge the response data with the client information that already exists.  Side note: `.success` and `.error` are deprecated, and `.then` should be used instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6

Comment: obviously your `$scope.data` will change its contents because you're changing the whole reference, try this  `$scope.data.portfolios = response.data`

Comment: Check your capitalization -- `Name != name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you losing `portfolios` property while assigning `response.data` to the `$scope.data`. So, `ng-repeat` will never render as there is no property `portfolios` after assigning `response.data`.

So, *its not about watch* , angular is still watching `$scope.data` , its just that `ng-repeat` cant find `portfolios` property anymore [Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DQ0ZznzKvdhwTaxZj97c?p=preview)

Just change your code to

```
$http.get('data.json')
 .then(function (response) {
    $scope.data.portfolios = response.data;
});
```

Also, **Dont use `success` as it has been deprecated**

One other scenario [which is covered in plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/siapXv4vKrGrLv5rL8Pz?p=preview) . Let me know if it covers what you were looking for. In here, I have assigned a `property` to `$scope.data`

Comment: The problem is "response.data" has about a dozen other properties... so I would have to copy them one by one... it sounds like, then, that once $scope.data is assigned... there is no way to reconnect the html to the new data?

Comment: @BrianRice : Can you check https://plnkr.co/edit/siapXv4vKrGrLv5rL8Pz?p=preview and let me know if this is what you were concerned abt ? can you create a plunkr to explain better your problem ? I think my 2 plunkrs is covering what you are looking for

Comment: Ok... do your example works exactly like what I wanted... not sure why this doesn't seem to work in my code... will examine further... thanks!

Comment: @BrianRice : Sure, just check if it's related to `digest` cycle in your case. :)